# printing eprinttype in small caps with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber, small-caps

I'm using biblatex + biber to print the bibliography. I want the eprinttype (PMID in my case) to be printed in small caps just like URL, DOI etc. Here's what I've tryed so far which did not change anything.

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{eprint}{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}
```

or

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{eprint}{\mkbibacro{#1}}
```

(both with {eprint} and {eprinttype})

Am I using the wrong field name?
Is there any list of abbreviations that PMID can be added to?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `eprinttype` field is a "verbatim" field and its contents can only be one of the `biblatex` predefined.

If you want to change such a field, only "PMID" in your case, the best thing to do is to change its original definition as it's written in the file `biblatex.def`.

Thus, in your `.tex` file, write the lines:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{eprint:pubmed}{%
  \mkbibacro{PMID}\addcolon\space
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}}
```

so that, when in your `.bib` file you write

```
eprinttype = {pubmed},
```

you'll get "PMID" in small caps.